# How to improve the security and privacy of Firefox

Tags: web-browser, privacy, firefox, browser-extensions, internet

What would be a **sensible** approach to enhance the security and privacy of Firefox?

I did not find a question about this and I feel that some guidelines for casual web users would be handy.

Currently my browser is wearing:

- [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus) to block pesky ads and social network buttons;
- [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) to rewrite HTTP requests as HTTPS when possible; and
- [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery) to block the [widely used](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/traffic_analysis/all) Google Analytics.

The first two have been in use for a long time. The latter was installed today and I'm still assessing how it fares since *I've heard* it breaks some web sites.

Feel free to post an answer for the most paranoid of us using [VM inception](https://superuser.com/q/312433) and the likes. As for the rest of the world, what else would you add to the list and why? Please keep [usability](https://blog.kaspersky.com/usability-and-security-the-endless-pursuit-of-perfection/) in mind.

Comment: Four points: (1) Privacy and security are often interdependent, actions taken to improve one sometimes improves the other; (2) The browser is just one of many components that need attention for best security and privacy; (3) As you probably realize, usability can suffer with blocking add-ons - page elements may not function properly and whole pages may not function; (4) Be aware that many browser mods will actually increase your susceptibility to fingerprinting. See, for example: https://panopticlick.eff.org

Comment: Especially because of #4 above, from a privacy perspective, a common browser UA in a VM set up as a common OS config, with aggressive cookie management and without loading Flash or Java, can be reasonably effective. Vary your IP addresss. Even better: use the Tor version of Firefox for as much anonymous browsing as possible. HTTPS and Tor are your best friends for security too. If you can articulate your security & privacy threat model, recommendations become easier to prioritize (e.g., are you more concerned about government, local ISP, café wi-fi, or commercial tracking across web sites?).

Comment: To address fingerprinting, it's better to partition your web use across different personas for different purposes, and keep each persona in a different physical machine or VM (with differently-configured VM/browser combinations). But again, Tor browser bundle is a very easy way to achieve high levels of anonymity when used properly.

Comment: I use flashblock, too, partially because of security. And instead of adblock plus I use adblock edge (it doesn't have an exception list).

Comment: @PeterHorvath: *"instead of adblock plus I use adblock edge (it doesn't have an exception list)"* -- There is an option in Adblock Plus that you can uncheck: `Allow some non-intrusive advertising`.

Comment: I personally recommend Adblock for Firefox its use much lower memory than adblock plus

Comment: @Freedom: *"recommend Adblock for Firefox its use much lower memory than adblock plus*" -- `Adblock Plus` doesn't call home like `Adblock`. `Adblock Plus` does allow some advertising to pass but like I mentioned above that can be disabled in options and is clearly visible whereas in the case of `Adblock` you cannot disable the tracking as far as I am aware of. For more info read [one](https://palant.de/2014/07/29/which-is-better-adblock-or-adblock-plus) then [two](http://blog.getadblock.com/2014/07/adblock-and-privacy.html). Disclaimer: I have no stakes in either of them.

Comment: @Daniel good to know but seems to me that none are trustful anymore so i recommend ublock now and i'm even planning to write an adblock extension by myself (the old rule : only trust the code yourself made)

Comment: It is nice to know there are people around collecting hardening guidelines: https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js

Answer (score 6):

There are several actions you can take in order to secure Firefox, how far you chose to go is of course up to you.

You can make some modifications in the Firefox preferences menu:

- "General"

  - "when Firefox starts"->"Show a blank page"
  - "save files to:"Downloads"
- "Content"

  - check:"Block pop-up windows"
  - uncheck:"Enable
    JavaScript"
  - "Languages"->choose *only*:"en-us"
- "Applications"->choose:"Always ask" for every application
- "Privacy"

  - "Tracking"->check:"Tell websites I do not want to be
    tracked"
  - "History"->"Firefox will:"Use custom settings for
    history"
  - "History"->uncheck:"Always use private browsing
    mode"
  - "History"->uncheck:"Remember my browsing and
    download history"
  - "History"->uncheck:"Remember search and
    form history"
  - "History"->uncheck:"Accept cookies from
    sites"
  - "History"->uncheck:"Accept third-party cookies"
  - "History"->check:"Clear history when Firefox/Nightly
    closes"
  - "History"->"settings":check all -> except:"Site
    Preferences"
  - "location bar"->"When using the location bar,
    suggest:"->choose:"Nothing"
- "security"

  - check:"Warn me when sites try
    to install add-ons"
  - check:"Block reported attack sites"
  - check:"Block reported web forgeries"
  - "Passwords"->uncheck:"Remember passwords for sites"
  - "Passwords"->uncheck:"Use a master password"
- "advanced"

  - "General"->"System Defaults"->uncheck:"Submit crash
    reports"
  - "General"->"System Defaults"->uncheck:"Submit
    performance data"
  - "Update"->check:"Automatically install
    updates"
  - "Update"->check:"Warn me if this will disable
    any of my add-ons"
  - "Update"->check:"Automatically update
    Search Engines"
  - "Encryption"->"Protocols"->check:"Use SSL
    3.0"
  - "Encryption"->"Protocols"->check:"Use TLS 1.0"
  - "Encryption"->"Certificates"->"When a server requests my
    personal certificate"->check:"Ask me every time"

Addons

Empty Cache Button [optional]

Calomel SSL Validation [cool little addon which does exactly what its name says and also has some more tweaks in the settings]

Adblock Edge

Easylist

EasyPrivacy

fanboy-adblock

Fanboy's Tracking List

Fanboy's Annoyance List

BetterPrivacy [LSO/Flash-Cookie-Protection]

Cookie Monster [Allows you to Manage your Cookie-Policies. For less baggage use Firefox/Iceweasel "Preferences" -> "Privacy"]

HTTPS-Everywhere [Download via EFF.org] [settings: enable SSL-Observatory but don't allow to transmit ISP-data]

HTTPS Finder

NoScript [go to "settings" and check "also apply on whitelisted sites"]

Perspectives [SSL-Cerfiticate-Control - go to settings: "notary servers" -> check "only contact when websites cause security error"]

RefControl [controls your HTTP-Referers - setting: "block" -> "3rd parties only"]

Request Policy [rejects cross-site requests]

WOT [Web of Trust - user based website ratings that show up in websearches. Caution: Not very accurate. Always double check when in doubt. This addon tends
to get abused by different groups of users who either give malicious sites good ratings - or flag perfectly good sites.]

PwdHash [Nice addon to help your password management. Use "F2" when entering a password into a password field when setting up a new account somewhere to create a MD5-hash using your password and the domain. (When logging in you have to select the password-field and press F2 again to run the hashing.) This way you can use the same password on different sites without having to worry about security implications - because every site gets its own password generated through the hash. The tool is provided by Standford University and can be trusted. No data is actually transmitted to their servers. The hash is generated using your local java-script. If you need to login from a machine that doesn't have pwdhash installed: go to https://www.pwdhash.com/ -> their SSL is very strong.]

FoxyProxy [a convenient Proxy Switcher]

Useragent Switcher [Does exactly that. But be careful: If you set your user-agent as shown below - using this addon it will overwrite these settings and will not automatically restore them if you turn off the switcher. So you would have to manually reconfigure about:config again. Which sucks. But you can get a whole load really cool user agents here. Simply download the .xml and import it to the Useragent Switcher. There are really neat current agents in there: e.g. all kinds of different web browser for all OSs and of course various bots. Google bot comes in handy when you need access to some forum... wink]

Web Developer [Has some cool features. If you like inspecting websites just check it out.]

Bloody Vikings [Creates disposable mail-addresses]

Note: You don't need Ghostery. The above mentioned Adblock lists do a much better job protecting you from web-tracking without using the additional resourced Ghostery uses.

Of course there are more addons you could use. But I don't really see the point of them. Most of them either are snake-oil or even dangerous.
To keep your ISP and possible MITM-attackers from reading what you do on the web always use SSL - as far as it is available. To help with this use:

SSL-Search Engines

The user "SSL Search Bar" has provided easily installable SSL-searchbar-plugins

You get SSL-plugins for all the alternative search-engines like ixquick, duckduckgo etc. there. Install those you happen to use.

Privatelee also looks promising. But I haven't tried it out extensively.

The next thing to do is to change macromedias flash-settings:

Flash-Settings

Go here.

And fight yourself through their nasty settings-manager. Set everything to "0" or "never allow"/"never ask again" and
delete all stored website-content. Give special attention to the webcam and Mic settings

You might as well set the permissions of your .macromedia folder to read only - but that's kind of unnecessary because you want to make sure to edit the options mentioned above - to make sure that you don't allow websites to use your mic or webcam I actually take this one step further by disabling them in BIOS.

You can also go one step further and run Firefox in a sandbox such as Sandboxie.

Just a general idea of the things you can do that will help secure your browser.

Comment: Secret Agent from https://www.dephormation.org.uk/index.php?page=81 is another great add-on for randomizing your user agent

Comment: Checking "block reported attack sites & web forgeries" queries Google to tell whether a domain is malicious or not; given that the author wants to hide from Google Analytics I think enabling that option is counter productive.

Comment: Completely turning off JavaScript and cookies will severely degrade usability on many sites. Also, some of the preferences settings depend on how Firefox is used. For example, it's OK to accept 1st-party cookies if you set up Firefox to clear all state when quitting and quit often.

Comment: Self destructing cookies is the best add on to manage cookies it will only let cookies remain as long as you are using that page close it and the cookies are gone! Won't break any page and is closer to cookieless browsing and you can whitelist sites you want to keep logged

Comment: All excellent points

Comment: Extensions may be able to access elements of your browsing traffic. I have a certain level of trust of Mozilla, but I don't necessarily have that same level of trust for arbitrary extension developers. Need to weigh risk for a given extension with the benefit it provides.

Comment: Absolutely its important to vet any type of software before relying on it.

Comment: Turning off all cookies is somewhat impractical since it breaks a lot of stuff. Similarly, turning off all third-party cookies leads to very annoying problems. There are however a lot of hidden options to help users reduce their cookie exposure: https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/tweaking-cookies-for-privacy-in-firefox/

Comment: **WARNING:** WOT-ratings may be (partly) ok, but do **NOT install any WOT-software**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html

Answer (score 2):

I will focus my answer in not so basic actions you can do to improve your security, add-ons and basic configuration i assume most security awaraness people already know so.

Go to about:config then search for :

security.ssl.require_safe_negotiation
 Set to it to true

security.warn_viewing_mixed
Set it to true

security.xpconnect.plugin.unrestricted
Set it to false (that may break plugins i didn't test it with the add-ons mentioned above if anyone can test that would be very good since i can't at moment)

privacy.trackingprotection.enabled
Set it to true

Also search for "rc4" (on the same config page!) disable all of then rc4 is insecure on that way you enforce stronger ciphers when establishing an SSL connection.

network.http.sendRefererHeader

```
0 – never send the referring URL.
1 – send only when links are clicked.
2 – send for links and images (default).
```

Recommended : 1

network.http.referer.XOriginPolicy

```
0 – always send referrer (default).
1 – only send if base domains match.
2 – only send if hosts match.
```

Recommended : 1

network.http.referer.spoofSource

```
false – send the referrer (default).
true – spoof the referrer and use the target URI instead.
```

Recommended : True

network.http.referer.trimmingPolicy

```
0 – send full URI (default).
1 – scheme, host, port and path.
2 – scheme, host and port.
```

Recommended : 2

Set network.proxy.socks_remote_dns (in about:config) to true to force Firefox to make DNS requests through the proxy. Otherwise you can leak DNS requests to your local provider.(thanks @pseudon)

Thats all i remember for now since i can't acess a desktop only firefox for android if anyone knows more to add to list feel free to edit/comment

Comment: If using SOCKS proxies (as you might with VMs), set network.proxy.socks_remote_dns (in about:config) to true to force Firefox to make DNS requests through the proxy. Otherwise you can leak DNS requests to your local provider.

Comment: Tighten up the about:config setting for network.http.sendRefererHeader to your liking (set to "0", or at worst to "1") http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader (or use a referer control add-on for more granularity).

Comment: Thanks @pseudon i've added the list with even a few more tweaks i found